# Grab first and last occurence per group over multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem description**

I have a couple of worksheets showing open and close values per group (track).
All rows come with a date.
I want to loop through all worksheet and grab the oldest value for column Open and the most recent value for column Close.
Pseudo code:

1. Oldest and newest value per group for first worksheet

Per worksheet, grab the oldest value for Open and the most recent value for Close per group

2. Go to next worksheet and compare values

Next, go to the next worksheet and compare the oldest and new values with the previously captured ones. Per group, override the oldest value with the corresponding value in the current worksheet if the date in the current worksheet is older.
Override the most recent value with the corresponding value if the date in the current worksheet is more recent.

3. Repeat step 2 until we've looped through all worksheets.

I've been able to capture the oldest and most recent values per worksheet.
However, I can't figure out how to loop through all the worksheets and grab the oldest and most recent values per group over all worksheets.

I'm a starter on Excel VBA and want to stick with simple loops as per my current code. I want to loop through the worksheets "as is" meaning no renaming and no merging into one worksheet before running any code (there could be over a million rows in total).

**Current code to grab the values per worksheet:**

```
Sub top_one()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim group_start As Double
Dim track As String
Dim start_date, end_date As Long
Dim opening, closing As Double

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "1" And WS.Name <> "Expected" Then
    WS.Select
    With WS
        LastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            group_start = 2
            If .Cells(i + 1, "A").Value <> .Cells(i, "A").Value Then
                group_start = i - group_counter
                track = .Cells(i, "A")
                start_date = .Cells(group_start, "B")
                opening = .Cells(group_start, "C")
                end_date = .Cells(i, "B")
                closing = .Cells(i, "D")
                'lastRowTotal = Sheets("1").Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "A") = .Cells(i, "A") 'trck
                'If opening_date < Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "B") Then
                    Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "B") = opening_date
                'Else
                'End If
                Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "B") = .Cells(group_start, "B") 'start date
                Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "C") = .Cells(i, "B") 'end date
                Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "D") = .Cells(group_start, "C") 'opening
                Sheets("1").Cells(j + 2, "E") = .Cells(i, "D") 'closing
                j = j + 1
                group_counter = 0
            Else
                group_counter = group_counter + 1
            End If
        Next
        j = 0
    End With
    End If
Next WS
End Sub
```

**Screendumps**

**Worksheets data**

*Worksheet called 2018*

```
Track   Date        Open    Close
A       20180101    1       5
A       20180102    4       8
A       20180103    4       5
B       20180104    12      1
B       20180105    2       4
C       20180106    5       2
C       20180107    2       5
E       20180108    8       9
```

*Worksheet called a*

```
Track   Date        Open    Close
A       20170101    5       6
A       20170102    6       6
B       20170103    2       1
B       20170104    1       2
C       20170105    5       9
C       20170106    9       7
D       20170107    5       5
D       20170108    5       8
D       20170109    7       2
```

*Worksheet called 145jki*

```
Track   Date        Open    Close
A       20160101    8       5
A       20160102    4       5
B       20160103    11      5
B       20160104    8       9
C       20160105    10      3
C       20160106    5       7
```

*Expected result*

```
Track   Start date  End date    First Open  Last Close
A       20160101    20180103            8           5
B       20160103    20180105            11          4
C       20160105    20180107            10          5
D       20170107    20170109            5           2
E       20180108    20180108            8           9
```

Comment: What about merging the data into an array then put the results in a new worksheet .. then deal with the new data in the new worksheet with your code?

Comment: That's what I ended up with, creating a new worksheet. Didn't use arrays though, I'm not that experienced on VBA and wanted to keep it plain and simple for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Grab_First_Last_Occurence_Per_Group_Across_Worksheets()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim a()         As Variant
Dim temp        As Variant
Dim prev        As Variant
Dim f           As Boolean
Dim i           As Long
Dim p           As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Name <> "1" And .Name <> "Expected" Then
                temp = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
                If f Then
                    a = ArrayJoin(a, temp)
                Else
                    a = temp
                    f = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    BubbleSort a, 2
    BubbleSort a, 1
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 5)

    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        If a(i, 1) <> prev Then
            p = p + 1
            b(p, 1) = a(i, 1)
            b(p, 2) = a(i, 2)
            b(p, 3) = a(i, 2)
            b(p, 4) = a(i, 3)
            b(p, 5) = a(i, 4)
            If p > 1 Then
                b(p - 1, 3) = a(i - 1, 2)
                b(p - 1, 5) = a(i - 1, 4)
            End If
            prev = a(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    With Sheets("1")
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Track", "Start Date", "End Date", "First Open", "Last Close")
        .Range("A2").Resize(p, UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function ArrayJoin(ByVal a, ByVal b)
Dim i           As Long
Dim ii          As Long
Dim ub          As Long

ub = UBound(a, 1)
a = Application.Transpose(a)
ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To ub + UBound(b, 1))
a = Application.Transpose(a)

For i = LBound(b, 1) To UBound(b, 1)
    For ii = 1 To UBound(b, 2)
        a(ub + i, ii) = b(i, ii)
    Next ii
Next i

ArrayJoin = a
End Function

Function BubbleSort(arr() As Variant, sortIndex As Long)
Dim b           As Boolean
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long

ReDim v(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Variant

Do
    b = True
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        If arr(i, sortIndex) > arr(i + 1, sortIndex) Then
            b = False
            For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                v(j) = arr(i, j)
                arr(i, j) = arr(i + 1, j)
                arr(i + 1, j) = v(j)
            Next
        End If
    Next i
Loop While Not b
End Function
```